# Subfolders with subreports in Reporting Services

Tags: report, reporting-services, subreport, subreports

Ok here is my scenario:
1 - A-type - big report with several subreports (C or D types)
10 - B-type - reports with one or two subreports (C or D Types)
20 - C-type - subreports that may or may not have subreports (D Type)
4 - D-Type - leaf base reports that may have D-type subreports

A and B reports have subreports with path SuBreports/ specified in Subreport properties
C and D have no extra path specified (just the name of the subreport)

Deploy A and B reports on ms rs server path \Reports
Deploy C and D in \Reports\SubReports

Now:
After deployment only A and B type reports will be accessed and in this configuration they work flawlessly.
In development mode I had to hack something together so I can have some order in this project so I made 1 solution with 2 projects (one for A and B type reports and the other for C and D type reports) and I placed them in the SAME folder so that the BIN folder would be the same for both (deploy and release are set both in the bin root folder) now OutputFolder for project 1 (A and B) is BIN and Output folder for project 2 (C and D) is BIN\SubReports.
Everything in Project 2 work great in development mode.

THE PROBLEM
In Project 1 I set for an A or B type report a subreport with the path SubReports/ because that is where in the BIN folder the subreports are stored. The A report goes to this folder and runs the report only the report has a subreport in the same SubReports/ folder and this get's me in an error.
I think it is because A report runs the C report (for example) with the path of A report (BIN folder) so the C report (which looks in the same folder for it's subreport) is now looking for it's subreport in the BIN folder instead of the BIN\SubReports folder.
How do I fix this?